# Add element in object in array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am new to JavaScript I am trying to combine two object from two arrays

First Array

```js
const TESTARRAY = [{
  id: 3,
  parameter1: 'x',
  parameter2: 'y',
  parameter3: 'z'
}, {
  id: 1,
  parameter1: 'u',
  parameter2: 'v',
  parameter3: 'w'
}, {
  id: 5,
  parameter1: 'q',
  parameter2: 'w',
  parameter3: 'e'
}]
```

Second array

```js
var json = [{
  name: 'aaa'
}, {
  name: 'ccc'
}, {
  name: 'bbb'
}];
```

Expected Output

```
[{
  additional: "aaa",
  id: 3,
  parameter1: "x",
  parameter2: "y",
  parameter3: "z"
}, {
  additional: "ccc",
  id: 1,
  parameter1: "u",
  parameter2: "v",
  parameter3: "w"
}, {
  additional: "bbb",
  id: 5,
  parameter1: "q",
  parameter2: "w",
  parameter3: "e"
}]
```

Code I tried below in JSFiddle I try to loop the var and add the element to TESTARRAY but I am getting same value "bbb" anyone can guide me for better approach?

```js
const TESTARRAY = [{
  id: 3,
  parameter1: 'x',
  parameter2: 'y',
  parameter3: 'z'
}, {
  id: 1,
  parameter1: 'u',
  parameter2: 'v',
  parameter3: 'w'
}, {
  id: 5,
  parameter1: 'q',
  parameter2: 'w',
  parameter3: 'e'
}]
var json = [{
  name: 'aaa'
}, {
  name: 'ccc'
}, {
  name: 'bbb'
}];

for (var key in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    TESTARRAY.map(i => i.additional = json[key].name)
  }
}


console.log(TESTARRAY)
```

Comment: You [don't have JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation). You have plain objects and plain arrays. JSON is a *text serialisation format* similar to XML. It will always be represented as a string.

Comment: Just loop and update same index of the array


for (const [k, v] of json.entries()) {TESTARRAY[k]['additional'] = v.name;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays you want to combine are the same size.
You can simply do something like this.

```
for (let i = 0; i < TESTARRAY.length; ++i)
{
    TESTARRAY[i] = {...json[i], ...TESTARRAY[i]};
}
```

Comment: Its working thank you very much for your time and help

Answer (score 3):

You could map a new array with merged properties of the second array at the same index.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ name: 'aaa' }, { name: 'ccc' }, { name: 'bbb' }],
    array2 = [{ id: 3, parameter1: 'x', parameter2: 'y', parameter3: 'z' }, { id: 1, parameter1: 'u', parameter2: 'v', parameter3: 'w' }, { id: 5, parameter1: 'q', parameter2: 'w', parameter3: 'e' }],
    merged = array1.map(({ name: additional }, i) => ({ additional, ...array2[i] }));

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It works also thank you really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`map` second argument is an `index` of the current item, you can use that to reference your `json` variable.

```js
const TESTARRAY = [{
    id: 3,
    parameter1: "x",
    parameter2: "y",
    parameter3: "z"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    parameter1: "u",
    parameter2: "v",
    parameter3: "w"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    parameter1: "q",
    parameter2: "w",
    parameter3: "e"
  }
];
var json = [{
    name: "aaa"
  },
  {
    name: "ccc"
  },
  {
    name: "bbb"
  }
];

const newTestArray = TESTARRAY.map((curr, index) => ({
  additional: json[index].name,
  ...curr
}));

console.log(newTestArray);
```